# What is being stored and where when you use cv2.VideoCapture()?

Tags: opencv, memory, camera, raspberry-pi

If I were to turn on my camera with `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, without any other code to read or save frames, is there anything being temporarily stored (i.e. in the heap)? If I do not release and have this process run continuously, will memory be built up until it is out of memory space?

Context:
I am currently using a Raspberry Pi camera and am thinking about using `cv2.VideoCapture()` followed by `read()` to replace `PiCamera().capture()` for the purpose of speed and efficiency. To put in other words, I am considering taking a frame from a video stream to use in place of a photo. As I consider the pros & cons, I came across this question. Any comments and/or advice is appreciated.

Note that I am also new to stack overflow, so if I apologize in advance for anything unconventional in this posting.

Comment: Try it. Start your code and monitor the process's memory usage with `htop` or similar. I think it buffers around 5 frames, so if you open and wait a few minutes then read some frames, the first 4-5 will be a few minutes old.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell for the response. However, I am unaware and cannot find a way to read older frames from `cv2.VideoCapture()`. I know OpenCV is open source, but I cannot find the code for VideoCapture. If anyone could point me in the right direction within OpenCV's github (https://github.com/opencv/opencv) or explain how the method works (beyond how a buffer works), this would be really helpful.