# Taking Frame from Video vs Taking a Photo

Tags: opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

My specific question is: What are the drawbacks to using a snipped frame from a video vs taking a photo?

Details:
I want to use frames from live video streams to replace taking pictures because it is faster. I have already researched and considered:

- Videos need faster shutter speed, leading to higher possibility of blurring
- Faster shutter speed also means less exposure to light, leading to potentially darker images
- A snipped frame from a video will probably be lower resolution (although maybe we can possibly turn up the resolution to compensate for this?)
- Video might take up more memory -- I am still exploring the details with another post ([What is being stored and where when you use cv2.VideoCapture()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462035/what-is-being-stored-and-where-when-you-use-cv2-videocapture))
- Anything else?

I will reword my question to make it (possibly) easier to answer: What changes must I make to a "snip frame from video" process to make the result equivalent to taking a photo? Are these changes worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum resolution in **picamera** is 2592x1944 for still photos and 1920x1080 for video recording. Other issues to take into account are that you cannot receive all formats from VideoCapture, so now conversion of the YUV frame to JPG will be your responsibility. OK, OpenCV can handle this, but it takes considerable CPU time and memory.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response (upvoted as thanks, but still seeking answer). For conversion, I actually use `image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`. `cap.read()` actually takes in BGR, and the conversion to RGB takes only 0.01s. YUV is not involved in this process. Therefore, conversion is not a problem. As for the issue with memory, I have already taken that into account when I mention _Video might take up more memory_.

Comment: I was addressing specifically the JPG format of saved picture.